# Trying to deploy new static content (images, css, javascript) to an ASP.Net webapp without triggering a restart of the project

Tags: asp.net, iis

I think there's a setting in IIS 7.5 or the web.config to control when the application pool is recycled/restarted when new files are added to the Site's directory.

But whenever I upload new image files for example, the whole application restarts and my users have their session killed.

I understand that uploading new DLLs and even ASPX pages could and should trigger such a restart, but how do I turn this off for static files?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE: Is it possibly related to the 'Handler Mappings'? There's an entry for '*' where I can specify what should be handled as static content.

Comment: Really strange behaviour, as I know the creation of a new folder causes the recycle of the application pool, but a single file in a non-system folder shouldn't... can you show your directories structure?